# Execute a function, if a condition is fulfilled. Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently validating a form. I have a function called "myFunction".

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" ng-click='myFunction()' >SEND</button>
```

I want the function to run when is clicked, if the form is valid, ie if

```
Form.$valid == true.
```

I need to do this directly in the html view, I should not and do not want to put anything in the controller. How can I do it?

http://jsfiddle.net/f8cqp791/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" ng-click='Form.$valid && myFunction()'>SEND</button>
```

In this case, if the form is not valid then nothing happens, otherwise, myFunction() is called.

Comment: great! but is "form.$valid && myFunction()"

Comment: what? can you please be more specific?

Comment: can you please accept the answer, if it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your html

```
ng-click='form.$valid && myFunction()'
```